# Как зациклить слайды в Swiper Slider

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы в слайдере Swiper при прокрутке последнего слайдера снова начиналось все по новой?
По дефолту он не дает его прокрутить.
В API не могу найти...

Comment: может быть Swiper slider ? тогда `loop: true`

Comment: помогло! Большое спасибо.

Comment: оформил в виде ответа. его можно принять галочкой слева от тела ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В API этого плагина указано следующее:

> **Parameter** loop
> **Type**  boolean
> **Default**   false
> **Description**  Set to true to enable continuous loop mode
>
> *If you use it along with slidesPerView: 'auto' then you need to specify loopedSlides parameter with amount of slides to loop (duplicate)*

Для активации зацикливания слайдов необходимо добавить `loop: true`.